# AngularJS and RequireJS add controller to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, requirejs

I have a problem with adding a **Angular controller** to my **HTML view**. The angular way of doing this is: `ng-controller="<controller>"`. But because I am using RequireJs I have to do this in a different way. I have to add a sub page to every controller and view:

```
define(['app', 'login/LoginController'], function (app, LoginController) {

    app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: "modules/" + 'login/login.html',
            controller: LoginController
        });
    });
    app.controller('LoginController', LoginController);

});
```

This way I can define my where my controller is and where my view is.

---

**Problem**

Now I have a header.html in which I want to include a menu.html. this can be done via: `ng-include="'modules/menu/menu.html'"`. This works fine. But how can I add a controller to this menu.html?

I have tried: `ng-controller="MenuController"` but then I get the error: '`Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MenuController' is not a function, got undefined`'. So I do not know how I should add a controller to my menu.html with RequireJS.

---

**MenuController**

my MenuController looks as follows:

```
define(['$'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var MenuController = function ($location, menu, $scope) {
        $scope.info="testing123";
    };
    return MenuController;
});
```

---

**Anyone knows how I should do this?**

Comment: You should register controller within the application that has this header.html. So it should be `app.controller('MenuController', MenuController);` where app is the app.

Comment: are you loading MenuController.js file before using ng-include?

Comment: @vpsingh016 I guess my view is loaded before my controller. But due to RequireJS, I cannot use 'ng-controller'. This will always result in an error

Comment: Use directive to load templete and respective controller. Then call directive inside header.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example use multiple views in the same `controller`with `$stateProvider`:

```
    app.config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'menu': {
                templateUrl: 'modules/menu/menu.html',
                controller: MenuController
            },
            'login': {
                templateUrl: 'modules/login/login.html'
                controller: LoginController
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Then in your template to call them you just need to do something like:

```
<div ui-view="menu"></div>
<div ui-view="login"></div>
```

You can see more info on [github ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

Comment: UI-Router fixed my problem. Now I can define a abstract template and dynamically change the different views on the template. I can also add a controller to every view.